# Why is there no lost+found directory in storage pool?

Tags: rhel, partition, kvm, storage, virsh

I am studying [this Red Hat documentation](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/Virtualization_Deployment_and_Administration_Guide/sect-Partition_based_storage_pools.html#sect-Partition_based_storage_pools-Creating_a_partition_based_storage_pool_using_virsh), which states that a validated storage pool should have a `lost+found` directory to indicate that it is properly mounted.

I have followed the instructions from the documentation explicitly, but yet my results (shown below) do not include a `lost+found` directory.

**Has this storage pool been properly mounted?  What else needs to be done in order for the storage pool described below to validate correctly?  Otherwise, if the below is validated as properly mounted, then please explain the underlying reasons.**

---

**Create and Start/AutoStart the Storage Pool:**

---

```
[root@remote-host ~]# virsh pool-define-as eighthPool fs - - /dev/mapper/centos-eighth - "/eighthPool"
Pool eighthPool defined

[root@remote-host ~]# virsh pool-build eighthPool
Pool eighthPool built

[root@remote-host ~]# virsh pool-start eighthPool
Pool eighthPool started

[root@remote-host ~]# virsh pool-autostart eighthPool
Pool eighthPool marked as autostarted
```

---

**Validate the Storage Pool:**

---

```
[root@remote-host ~]# virsh pool-list --all
 Name                 State      Autostart
-------------------------------------------
 eighthPool           active     yes
 home                 active     yes
 root                 active     yes
 someUserName         active     yes
 tmp                  active     yes

[root@remote-host ~]# virsh pool-info eighthPool
Name:           eighthPool
UUID:           230c3939-b009-4d28-97ff-09419492cd9b
State:          running
Persistent:     yes
Autostart:      yes
Capacity:       224.89 GiB
Allocation:     32.20 MiB
Available:      224.85 GiB

[root@remote-host ~]# mount | grep /eighthPool
/dev/mapper/centos-eighth on /eighthPool type xfs (rw,relatime,seclabel,attr2,inode64,noquota)

[root@remote-host ~]# ls -la /eighthPool
total 4
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root root    6 Mar 12 11:03 .
dr-xr-xr-x. 25 root root 4096 Mar 20 08:23 ..
[root@remote-host ~]#
```

---

**Other Contents Of The Physical Disk:**

---

For reference, the partitions of the hard disk prior to creating the new storage pool are listed as follows:

```
[root@remote-host ~]# fdisk -l
WARNING: fdisk GPT support is currently new, and therefore in an experimental phase. Use at your own discretion.

Disk /dev/sda: 2000.4 GB, 2000398934016 bytes, 3907029168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk label type: gpt

#         Start          End    Size  Type            Name
 1         2048       411647    200M  EFI System      EFI System Partition
 2       411648      1435647    500M  Microsoft basic
 3      1435648   3897165823    1.8T  Linux LVM

Disk /dev/mapper/centos-root: 53.7 GB, 53687091200 bytes, 104857600 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes

Disk /dev/mapper/centos-swap: 8187 MB, 8187281408 bytes, 15990784 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes

Disk /dev/mapper/centos-home: 241.6 GB, 241591910400 bytes, 471859200 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes

....Other extraneous stuff omitted for brevity.

Disk /dev/mapper/centos-eighth: 241.6 GB, 241587716096 bytes, 471851008 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
```

Answer (score 5):

lost+found is a directory typically created when a mountpoint gets formatted with a standard Linux filesystem, like ext. I haven't played much with XFS, but afaik lost+found is specific to the `fsck` tool and XFS doesn't use it, so I assume that XFS might not use the directory either.

In any case, the existence of lost+found (which you can normally rebuild using `mklost+found`) is not indicative of a libvirt storage pool's health really. It will work as long as libvirt and qemu have rw access to the mountpoint.

Answer (score 0):

`lost+found` is a place where orphaned inodes are placed after errors are found during a file system check (`fsck`).  XFS doesn't have one.